# Python keyboard hotkey with toggling of the Scroll Lock

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, python-keyboard

pre: I'm not familiar with the low level win32Api calls.
I was testing a python script that binds a key to call a function and to toggle a `Scroll Lock` as an indicator that the key-remapping is `ON` with the `keyboard` module.

Here is an example that it works for the `Caps Lock`:

```
import ctypes
import keyboard

dll = ctypes.WinDLL('User32.dll')

CAPS_LOCK = 0X14
def toggle(event):
    print(f'Caps Lock: {bool(dll.GetKeyState(CAPS_LOCK))}')
    keyboard.send('Caps Lock')


keyboard.on_release_key('F12', toggle, suppress=False)
keyboard.wait()
```

The output is:

```
Caps Lock: False
Caps Lock: True
```

If I debug the module, I can see that it runs it as:

```
_winkeyboard.py
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error = True)
user32.keybd_event(vk, code, event_type, 0)

the values are:
user32.keybd_event(20, 58, 0, 0)
```

So what's with the `Scroll Lock`? It does not turn it on or off.

```
keyboard.send('Scroll Lock')
...
user32.keybd_event(3, 57414, 0, 0)
```

It seems that the library does something wrong or I'm calling the wrong function.